# SQL Query between a date range and a time range in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, select, time, mariadb

I'm having trouble writing this query to give me any results. I'm using MariaDB as well.

```
SELECT CallDate AS Week_Of, AgentName,
        COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_Calls,
        SUM(case when Accepted = 'ANSWERED' then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Answered,
        SUM(case when Accepted = 'NO ANSWER' then 1 ELSE 0 end) AS NoAnswer
FROM jshou_custom.afterhours
WHERE CallDate >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 WEEK) 
AND TIME(CallDate) BETWEEN '17:00:00' AND '08:00:00'
GROUP BY AgentName
```

The DATE_ADD clause works just fine and gives results within that interval, but as soon as I add in the TIME function nothing is returned in the results. The CallDate format is `2021-09-21 HH:MM:SS` I have tried using HOUR as well in place of TIME, but it also returns nothing.

I'm trying to pull calls from any day within the range specified in the DATE_ADD clause. As long as it's between 1700 and 0800 (after hours calls).

Comment: Your `GROUP BY` columns are inconsistent with the `SELECT` columns.

Comment: I have to assume that a time range like that would traverse 2 days !!

Comment: Yes it would. So I would want to pull between 2021-09-21 17:00:00 and 2021-09-22 08:00:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to check both dates something like this and adjust the times used on each date as well

```
WHERE 
(CallDate > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -7 DAY) AND TIME(CallDate) > '17:00:00')
OR
(CallDate > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -6 DAY) AND TIME(CallDate) < '08:00:00')
```

Comment: Why use OR instead of AND?

Comment: Dont know, just a brain fart, changed it

Comment: This still brings back no results. However, if I comment out `AND
(CallDate > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -6 DAY) AND TIME(CallDate) < '08:00:00')` then it will bring back results after 17:00:00

Comment: If I comment out the other condition and uncomment the previous one, then it works as well. Seems like there's an issue when both are uncommented.

Comment: I just tried it again with the OR clause and it pulled results. You would think AND should be there but it does seems like you were right with the OR. Thanks for the help!